# Tinymce not rendering in form

Tags: django, tinymce

Attempting to use tinyMCE to allow rich input in blog content. I am constrained in that I am inside of Messanine using django 1.11.20. There seems to be many versions of tinyMCE so it is hard to google the right solution.

I used the documentation from Fosstack to install django-tinymce4-lite. Then integrated it into an existing update blog form. The form did not show the change, it still is rendering as a standard CharField. (TextField not supported in this version of django)

in views.py

```
class TinyMCEWidget(TinyMCE):
```

`       def use_required_attribute(self, *args):
            return False

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCEWidget(
            attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}
        )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['content']

def UpdateContent(request, slug): 
    blog_post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST)   
        if form.is_valid(): 
            blog_post.content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            blog_post.save()        
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/write/') 
    else:
        form = UpdateForm(instance=blog_post)
    return render(request, 'blog_my_update.html', {'form' : form})
```

in blog_my_update.html

```
<h1>Update Story</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
```

`   Update the Story

I expected to see the tinyMCE render the form. But got a normal text box. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that the css and javascript files of the library if they are being imported, try using `{{form.media}}` in the template, this should work if the library uses the django media form, otherwise, manually add the necessary files for the editor (css, javascript) and make sure you have some class or id that the editor usually uses to render the component

Comment: I attempted to add{{ form.media }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url "tinymce-js" "tinymce" %}"></script>                         but got error....Reverse for 'tinymce-js' not found. 'tinymce-js' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Yes, I do have the recommended url statement in place.  (This commenting system is not very good at formating)